# VueJS set custom component default value from props

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Hi guys I tried to create a VueJS custom component to wrap Vue Autonumeric component.

https://github.com/autoNumeric/vue-autoNumeric

In Vue Autonumeric page it specifically mention the caveat

> Caveats Please note that directly setting a :value='42' on the
>    component will break it (really!). Do NOT do that:

So in my custom component MoneyComponent.vue, I create a v-model

This is the full code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vue-autonumeric
                v-model="amount"
        ></vue-autonumeric>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VueAutonumeric from 'vue-autonumeric/src/components/VueAutonumeric.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            VueAutonumeric,
        },
        props: {
            value: {},
        },
        data() {
            return {
                amount: this.value,
            }
        },
        methods: {


        },
        watch: {

            amount (value) {
                this.$emit('input', value);
            }

        },
    }
</script>
```

Usage example

```
<template>
    <v-money
        v-model="price"
    ></v-money>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                price: 45,
            }
        },
        methods: {


        }
    }
<script>
```

This works on on initial value from parent. However if I change the price property to 55 for example, the amount property in MoneyComponent is not changing.

What is the problem here the amount property is not reactive on second changes? How do I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `v-model`, you need to emit `input` event to make data changed in the parent

```
    watch: {
      amount: function (newVal) {
        this.$emit('input', newVal)
      },
      value: function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          this.amount = newVal
        }
      }
    }
```

then your component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vue-autonumeric
          v-model="amount"
        ></vue-autonumeric>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VueAutonumeric from 'vue-autonumeric/src/components/VueAutonumeric.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            VueAutonumeric,
        },
        props: {
            value: {},
        },
        data() {
            return {
                amount: this.value,
            }
        },
        watch: {
          amount: function (newVal) {
            this.$emit('input', newVal)
          },
          value: function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
              this.amount = newVal
            }
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. Actually I already have the emit part, only left out from the example.

The actual problem is "How do I re-update the amount value in child component if parent change the price"?

Comment: pass the value down as props to the child, and then create a watcher that watches the prop and sets the value on change.

Comment: I updated my answer, You can watch for `value` change to update value in child component, too.

Comment: Thanks it works. Only parts that I cannot figure out is when we set the amount the value from watch, it will automatically trigger vee-validate, as if there is new value that was key in. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to trigger vee-validate? Or you don't want?

Comment: @ittus I dont want to trigger when we set the amount value using watch. Default it will be trigger